# Значение по умолчанию в теге <option>

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Есть цикл, который генерирует в форме теги в зависимости от количества записей в БД.

```
    <select class="form-control" name="publisher_id">
        <?php
        $results = DB::select('select * from publishers');

        foreach ($results as $value): ?>
          <option selected="" value="<?=$value->publisher_id;?>"><?=$value->name;?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>
```

Сама форма предназначена для редактирование записи и нужно в publisher вставить значение по-умолчанию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что select передаёт publisher_id, а при выборе выводится название издателя(то есть name).Оба этих поля находятся в таблице publishers, а сама форма по сути работает с таблицей books, где существует внешний ключ publisher_id. Нужно как-то в option selected поставить name из таблицы publisher, id которого соответствует внешнему ключу 'publisher_id' из таблицы books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно как-то в option selected поставить name из таблицы publisher, id
>   которого соответствует внешнему ключу 'publisher_id' из таблицы books

Вот тут ничего не понятно написано, было бы лучше показать пример кода, но могу предположить что у вас значение в `$publisher->id`, тогда достаточно добавить проверку в `option`, если не угадал, то подставьте свою переменную.

```
<select class="form-control" name="publisher_id">
    <?php
    $results = DB::select('select * from publishers');

    foreach ($results as $value): ?>
      <option value="<?=$value->publisher_id;?>" <?php if ($publisher->id == $value->publisher_id) echo 'selected';?>><?=$value->name;?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```